# Hewlett-Packard - Imaging - Null Print - HP Deskjet 3520 series - Error 0x8024200b

Tags: windows-10

I booted my windows 10 laptop after a long time. I ran an update (so that I have latest security updates) and it failed with error message

Hewlett-Packard  - Imaging - Null Print - HP Deskjet 3520 series - Error 0x8024200b

I googled on this subject and found some threads on HP forum which are totally useless ... the solutions given there do not work. I removed all HP software from my laptop because I don't use HP printers anymore. I have already gone to device manager and deleted the HP printer device and Yes I rebooted my machine 10 times already.

but windows 10 is **hell bent** on installing this update and will always fail.

What I want to do is to tell windows 10 not to update the printer and continue with other updates.

Windows 10 is so stupid and frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Hewlett-Packard - Imaging - Null Print - HP Deskjet 3520 series - Error 0x8024200b**

In the below order, follow these instructions until you resolve or complete each:

- You will want to ensure that all unknown printers, invalid
  drivers, defined printers, and all related software is uninstalled first and
  then reboot the machine.<sup>[1]</sup>
- If the problem is still there then you will want to download and run the [Microsoft Show or Hide Update Tool](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/2/F22D5FDB-59CD-4275-8C95-1BE17BF70B21/wushowhide.diagcab) and then reboot then machine.<sup>[2]</sup>
- If the problem is still there you should download and run the [Fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed](http://aka.ms/Program_Install_and_Uninstall) and then reboot the machine.<sup>[3]</sup>
- If the problem is still there you will then want to [Reset Windows Update Components](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/unable-to-install-update-error-0x8024200b/b5253e97-9595-4cd0-b631-9634e1a5b4f4) as described there, and then reboot the machine.<sup>[4]</sup>
- If the problem is still there, you will want to run the [SFC /SCANNOW](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833) as described in that article.<sup>[5]</sup>

> ### [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/hewlett-packard-imaging-null-print-hp-deskjet-3510/1b41a313-96e6-43da-b9f7-6a65fb95d93d)<sup>[1]</sup>
>
> I had the same problem. Here is how to fix it:
>
> - Right click on the Start Menu icon.
> - Click on Device Manager.
> - Click on Printers
> - On my PC there were two drivers called "Invalid Print Drivers. "Right    click on any invalid print drivers and delete them.
>
> This link shows how to hide the invalid update and stop it reoccurring
>   in future builds.
>
> http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/how-to-block-automatic-reinstall-of-a-driver-or/bff07224-4ce2-4b42-ab29-68c3a305d730
>
> <sub>[source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/hewlett-packard-imaging-null-print-hp-deskjet-3510/1b41a313-96e6-43da-b9f7-6a65fb95d93d)</sub>

---

> ### [How to temporarily prevent a Windows or driver update from reinstalling in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930)<sup>[2]</sup>
>
> **Resolution**
>
> If a driver or update you are being offered is causing system crashes
>   or instability and Windows was operating correctly prior to that
>   update, you can follow these instructions to prevent the unwanted
>   driver or update from being installed:
>
> To uninstall the unwanted driver:
>
> 1. Launch the **Device Manager** with a right click on the lower left
>      corner of the desktop and a left click on **Device Manager**.
> 2. Located the device driver with the problem driver installed, right
>      click and choose Uninstall.
> 3. In the uninstall dialog, check the box to **Delete the driver software
>      for this device** if available.
>
> To uninstall an unwanted Windows Update:
>
> 1. Type “View Installed Updates” in the Search box and then click on
>      **View Installed Updates – Control Panel** from the Search results.
> 2. To uninstall the unwanted update, select it from the list and then
>      click **Uninstall**.
>
> To temporarily prevent the driver or update from being reinstalled
>   until a new driver or updated fix is available, a troubleshooter is
>   available that provides a user interface for hiding and showing
>   Windows Updates and drivers for Windows 10. You can obtain and run the
>   "Show or hide updates" troubleshooter by downloading it from the
>   Microsoft Download Center.
>
> The following file is available for download from the Microsoft
>   Download Center:
>
> [Download the "Show or hide updates" troubleshooter package
>   now.](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/2/F22D5FDB-59CD-4275-8C95-1BE17BF70B21/wushowhide.diagcab)
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930)</sub>

---

> ### [Reset Window Updates Components](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/unable-to-install-update-error-0x8024200b/b5253e97-9595-4cd0-b631-9634e1a5b4f4)<sup>[4]</sup>
>
> Please follow the below steps to **reset the Windows Updates
>   Components**:
>
> 1. Press **Windows Key + X** on the keyboard and then select “Command
>      Prompt (Admin)” from the menu.
> 2. Stop the **BITS, Cryptographic, MSI Installer** and the **Windows Update
>      Services**. To do this, type the following commands at a command
>      prompt. Press the “ENTER” key after you type each command.
>
>    ```
>                   net stop wuauserv
>                   net stop cryptSvc
>                   net stop bits
>                   net stop msiserver
>    ```
> 3. Now rename the **SoftwareDistribution** and **Catroot2** folder. You can do this by typing the following commands in the Command
>      Prompt. Press the “ENTER” key after you type each command.
>
>    ```
>                   ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
>                   ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
>    ```
> 4. Now, let’s restart the BITS, Cryptographic, MSI Installer and the Windows Update Services. Type the following commands in the
>      Command Prompt for this. Press the ENTER key after you type each
>      command.
>
>    ```
>                net start wuauserv
>                net start cryptSvc
>                net start bits
>                net start msiserver
>    ```
> 5. Type **Exit** in the **Command Prompt** to close it.
>
> Now you may try running the Windows Updates and check if the above
>   steps resolve the issue.
>
> For further reference, you can refer to the link:
>
> **How do I reset Windows Update components?**
>
> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058/en-us
>
> <sub>[source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/unable-to-install-update-error-0x8024200b/b5253e97-9595-4cd0-b631-9634e1a5b4f4)</sub>

Comment: I have already read these. I have already gone to device manager and under printers removed the HP printer and rebooted. However Windows 10 is hell bent on installing it.

Comment: I tried many things and suddenly I noticed that the problem is gone. I don't know exactly what step made it go away.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem. I was using my 3520 printer wireless so I plugged in the USB cable and tried to install the update and it installed with no problems. I did not get an error message.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP wants to **prevent** the update.